esp32 s3 does not connect with micro ros after first connection, needs hardware reset to connect again
I am new in robotics and would like to ask some help.
I am using ESP32 s3 N16r8 for a project with a micro ROS on it for communication.
It is only subscribing to a topic.
It's working fine if you first plug the esp32 and execute the script (for running the agent and publishing topic). But if you kill/stop the script, it won't connect to micro ros again, unless you make a hardware reset.
I tried to use the following in code in setup function:
//wait agent comes up
do {
    EXECUTE_EVERY_N_MS(300, state = (RMW_RET_OK == rmw_uros_ping_agent(100, 1)) ? AGENT_AVAILABLE : WAITING_AGENT;);
    digitalWrite(LED_BUILTIN, !digitalRead(LED_BUILTIN));
    delay(300);

    if (state == AGENT_AVAILABLE)
    break;
} while (1);

Then for the loop function
switch (state) {
case AGENT_AVAILABLE:
  //if setup done, always here. then go to next step
  state = AGENT_CONNECTED;
  break;
case AGENT_CONNECTED:
  EXECUTE_EVERY_N_MS(500, state = (RMW_RET_OK == rmw_uros_ping_agent(30, 1)) ? AGENT_CONNECTED : AGENT_DISCONNECTED;);     
  if (state == AGENT_CONNECTED) {
    audio.setVolume(20);
    rclc_executor_spin_some(&executor, RCL_MS_TO_NS(10));
  }
  break;
case AGENT_DISCONNECTED:
  //if ping doesn't work, then reset board(=wait agent comes up)
  ESP.restart();
  break;
default:
  break;

}
I am not using wifi, only serial communication.
Am I missing something?
Any help is highly appreciated, thank you!
